# sending from one queue to other queues

Tags: c#, msmq

Ive a requirement to create a windows service which will pick up and send each message in a msmq to each queue in a list of queues held in a config file.
Ive only done some basic msmq work before, so forgetting the service part for the moment, Im guessing,

set the 'in' queue,

set an array to hold the 'out queues,

for each msg in the 'in' queue, send it to each queue in the array.

Ive always just picked up a message and sent it straight on, should I be worrying about formatting? And is there anything else I should look out for?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been working with MSMQ for some time now. I have only really run into a couple issues, which may not even affect you.

If you are trying to send messages over 4mb, you might want to look into other options, as of right now, that's the limit.

If you are trying to set up MSMQ over HTTPS (IIS hosted), it's EXTREMELY FIDGETY. It's also really hard to tell what's going wrong, as you don't get any useful error messages (if you get any at all)

I've used this site quite a bit for problems: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/

Oh, you also don't need to worry about formatting anything.